# Get byte[] from the SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, arrays

I have a table with a **varbinary(MAX)** parameter. After executing the query, I will store the result in SqlDataReader as it has multiple columns as output.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select leave_details from LeaveTable");
SqlDataReader obj;
con.Open();
obj = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Now I want to convert the result for each row into `byte[]`.

This one is not working:

```
byte[] b=null;
obj.GetBytes(0,0,b,0,1024);
```

Comment: What means "this one is not working"? Do you get an exception, the wrong result or a bsod?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The API call he tried to use is obviously wrong. I can't figure out why it even exists because the other necessary API to use it (length of binary blob to fetch) is missing altogether.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try `GetValue()` method.

```
byte[] b=null;
b=(byte [])obj.GetValue(0);
//OR
b=(byte [])obj[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string bytesfromsql = "01010101010110010111010001"; //for example
byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesfromsql.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Count(); i++)
{
   bytes[i] = byte.Parse(bytesfromsql[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: The bytes coming back from SQL **is not a string**. Also: even if it was, you would have to use `Convert.ToByte(string,int)` to specify the *radix* (is it base-2? base-10? base-16?) and in most cases: the length of a string is not the length of the decoded byte[]; in the case of base-16 it would be half the length of the input string - for example